# Checkbox does not align with prompt using Bootstrap class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have a Checkbox using Bootstrap checkbox-inline and the checkbox is embedded in the text prompt "Remember me on *this computer" - checkbox appears in the location indicated by `*`.

This is using a code snippet from Ruby on Rails tutorial (Hartl) Chapter 9 using the code segment pasted below.

How do I get the checkbox to appear before the prompt? Running this on C9 / AWS

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "checkbox inline" do %>
           <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
           <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Bootstrap is concerned, that tutorial seems to be a bit outdated. (not surprising given that the release version of Bootstrap 4 is barely a month old at this point).

### Edit:

I only realized what you actually wanted after editing your question (the asterisk was hidden initially, so it was a bit confusing)

Now, in order to make the checkbox appear **between** the words *"Remember me on"* and the words *"on this computer"*, you need the following HTML structure in Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label mr-2">Remember me on</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">this computer</label>
</div>
```

And if you want it the checkbox to appear before the entire prompt, you'll need the following HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Remember me on this computer</label>
</div>
```

Adjust your Rails code accordingly.

For more options, check out this reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios

Comment: Just updated my answer and code snippet based on the new information I discovered when editing your answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry I wasnt clearer about my question. AM using the 4th edition so yes, probably a but outdated. Actually I was trying not to have the checkbox appear in the middle of the prompt, the asterisk was to indicate where it was appearing with my code. Needed it to appear before the entire prompt text and that does not seem to work with the combination of class"checkbox inline" and <span> for prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer. I this case, you'll need to output the HTML shown in the second snippet. So, adjust your rails code accordingly. There's no `<span>` and no `checkbox inline` class in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: That helped - thanks! Original problem was with "checkbox inline" so changing to the correct Bootstrap class fixed it